# savePolygonFileSTL doesn't save correctly

Tags: c++, stl, vtk, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

using the function savePolygonFileSTL in my code I obtain an empty file of only 1KB in which is written only:

> solid ascii
>
> endsolid

I used OrganizedFastMesh function to get the mesh, but I obtain different results saving it as VTK file than STL file. The VTK file contains really the mesh, the STL file no. Why?

Here is my code:

```
io::saveVTKFile ("cat.vtk",mesh_ofm);
io::savePolygonFileSTL ("cat.stl",mesh_ofm);
```

Please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could no one help me?

Comment: Posting on the mailing list doesn't garanty help. It's really unorganized and also hard to use, because it's not working user friendly at all.

Comment: @ Laszlo-Andras Zsurzsa I don't understand what do you want to say? What is unorganized and also hard to use?

Comment: @ Laszlo-Andras Zsurzsa, thanks for the advice, but I need anyway a help for this issue

Comment: No one could help me? No one has the same problem?

Comment: I used `pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ>::reconstruct `function to generate mesh, with this parametres: `ofm.setInputCloud(cloud_smoothed);
 ofm.setMaxEdgeLength(3);
 ofm.setTriangulationType(pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ>::TRIANGLE_RIGHT_CUT);`